# Pandas Set multiple column and row values to nan based on another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two large dataframes, `df1`:

```
Col1    Col2    Val1    Val2    Val3
asd     ASYL    4.2             4.2
ppq     CONE            35      35
DA      HU      100     100
```

And `df2` is

```
Col1    Col2    Val1    Val2  Val3
asd     ASYL    7       12    17
ppq     CONE    17      19    19
DA      HU      5       14    13
```

Both dataframes have same index columns `Col1` and `Col2` and same value columns `Val1, Val2, Val3`.

I want to set the values in `df2` to `nan` where it is `Null` in `df1` to get the following:

```
Col1    Col2    Val1    Val2  Val3
asd     ASYL    7             17
ppq     CONE            19    19
DA      HU      5       14
```

I tried the following:

```
idx = df1.isnull()
df2.loc[idx] = np.nan
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`df.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with [`df.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html)

```
df2.where(df1.notna())

Col1    Col2    Val1   Val2  Val3
asd     ASYL    7      NaN    17
ppq     CONE   NaN      19    19
DA      HU      5       14    NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way

```
df1.mask(df1.notna(),df2)
```

Alternatively

```
m=df1.notna()

pd.DataFrame(np.where(m, df2, np.nan))
```

[image]

Comment: See two alternatives to @Ch3steR solution